# Post the Content of the data variable to valid JSON format

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs, post

I am trying to send JSON data to server (https://exampleurl.com/example?data=)
by setting the content of the data variable to valid JSON with the following properties name , email , urls.

Comment: if you pass data in URL, then I guess you pass parameters in URL and you can get the data and convert them to JSON format.

Comment: can you send example of valid JSON format ? as i already tried but not getting 200 response.

Comment: see this example of parameter to json converter in JAVA http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381446/how-to-convert-url-parameteres-to-json-format/29388163#29388163 and get some inspiration. you can find tons of info on how to format JSON

Comment: More practical way is to send JSON data via POST (ajax)

Comment: Hi, have you tried JSON.stringify(json)?

Comment: I tried with this function but not getting 200 response
<script type="text/javascript">
function send_json()
{
form = document.forms["form"]
data = {};
data['name'] = form["name"].value;
data['email'] = form["email"].value;
data['urls'] = form["urls"].value.split("\n");
url = "(https://exampleurl.com/example?data=";
client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("POST", url, false);
client.setRequestHeader("Contenttype","application/json");
client.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
</script>

Comment: @KN_ most I think most easiest way is send JSON data via Ajax post but not getting 200 response.

Comment: why i am getting this error message while sending request via Ajax ?

 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: @DataVelocity you need to allow CORS http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send `JSON` data in url. You need to pass the `JSON` data in the request body.

If using jQuery, use the following code:

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```