# How to pass url arguments (query string) to a HTTP request on Angular?

Tags: http, angular, typescript

I would like to trigger HTTP request from an Angular component, but I do not know how to add URL arguments (query string) to it.

```js
this.http.get(StaticSettings.BASE_URL).subscribe(
  (response) => this.onGetForecastResult(response.json()),
  (error) => this.onGetForecastError(error.json()),
  () => this.onGetForecastComplete()
)
```

Now my `StaticSettings.BASE_URL` is like a URL without query string like: `http://atsomeplace.com/` but I want it to be like `http://atsomeplace.com/?var1=val1&var2=val2`

How to add `var1`, and `var2` to my HTTP request object as an object?

```js
{
  query: {
    var1: val1,
    var2: val2
  }
}
```

and then just the HTTP module does the job to parse it into URL query string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541801/how-to-send-json-data-in-url-as-request-parameters-in-java refer this. Create URL before call and pass it to subscribe function in place of BASE_URL. 2cents

Answer (score 397, accepted):

The **[HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)** methods allow you to set the **params** in it's options.

You can configure it by importing the **[HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/api/common/http)** from the @angular/common/http package.

```js
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpClientModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

After that you can inject the **HttpClient** and use it to do the request.

```js
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.httpClient.get('/url', {
      params: {
        appid: 'id1234',
        cnt: '5'
      },
      observe: 'response'
    })
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(console.log);
  }
}
```

For angular versions prior to version 4 you can do the same using the **Http** service.

The **Http.get** method takes an object that implements [RequestOptionsArgs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptionsArgs-interface.html) as a second parameter.

The **search** field of that object can be used to set a string or a [URLSearchParams](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html) object.

An example:

```js
 // Parameters obj-
 let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
 params.set('appid', StaticSettings.API_KEY);
 params.set('cnt', days.toString());

 //Http request-
 return this.http.get(StaticSettings.BASE_URL, {
   search: params
 }).subscribe(
   (response) => this.onGetForecastResult(response.json()), 
   (error) => this.onGetForecastError(error.json()), 
   () => this.onGetForecastComplete()
 );
```

The documentation for the **Http** class has more details. It can be found [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html) and an working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/pKdztZBHr0wr1YLmmI8P?p=preview).

Comment: yw, I'll add an example soon, or you can do it if you have it working already. :)

Comment: A gist: https://gist.github.com/MiguelLattuada/bb502d84854ad9fc26e0 how to use URLSearchParams object, thanks again @toskv

Comment: Super slick with the URLSearchParams! Solved my issue with serializing JSON object.

Comment: There is no need for the variables, just use string interpolation with {
   search: ``var1=${val1}&var2=${val2}``
 }

Comment: Does that mean, if I already have a link containing parameters (string), I have to cut it into pieces and rebuild it as the second method parameter?

Comment: @Stefan no, it should work just fine if you use i as the url.

Comment: can o pass the whole object? i don't want to mess with each param in my service

Comment: @Toolkit looking at the api it is you can't give an object. If type safety is not a priority it might be that something like SilmSlim proposed might suit you better.

Comment: @Toolkit it should also be fairly easy to itterate over an object's keys and have them set in the params object.

Comment: @toskv. i too had similar kind of issue but mine is quite different. your ans helped me getting url binding with params.                                      finally i need to build an url to call my rest api server using this url ( http://testsite.com/category/page/:pageId/:activeFilter )

i tried a lot. but it is not coming as i expected, this is what i am getting /category/page/?pageId=0&activeFilter=1  in my server console. i want to send only numerical number like `/category/page/0/1`

any suggestions please

Comment: @SukumarMS there's really no need for anything special since it's part of the path. Just concatenate the strings 'blabla.com/page/' + page +'/activeFilter' + activeFilter. Or if you want to use template literals \`blabla.com/page/${page}/${activeFilter}\`.

Comment: @toskv is there any way to iterate the params in the class URLSearchParams once they are set?

Comment: @ocespedes check the documentation, there's a paramsMap property on the UrlSearchParams class.

Comment: this works for me: `http.get(url, {params: {var1: val1, var2: val2}})`

Comment: `search` property has been depricated from 4.0.0 -> use `params` instead

Comment: you are right, I'll update the answer with the 4.0.0 way of doing it

Comment: I am wondering if this query params are best handled in the component or in the service?

Comment: @Winnemucca that depends on your application. It works anywhere.

Comment: Just as a side note URLSearchParams is deprecated

Comment: @Musa you are right, I'll add a comment saying that.

Answer (score 205):

### Edit Angular >= 4.3.x

[HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) has been introduced along with [HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams). Below an example of use :

```
import { HttpParams, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('var1', val1);
params = params.append('var2', val2);

this.http.get(StaticSettings.BASE_URL, {params: params}).subscribe(...);
```

---

(Old answers)

### Edit Angular >= 4.x

`requestOptions.search` has been deprecated. Use `requestOptions.params` instead :

```
let requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.params = params;
```

---

### Original answer (Angular 2)

You need to import `URLSearchParams` as below

```
import { Http, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
```

And then build your parameters and make the http request as the following :

```
let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('var1', val1);
params.set('var2', val2);

let requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.search = params;

this.http.get(StaticSettings.BASE_URL, requestOptions)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json())
...
```

Comment: Not working for me.
I digged into the source code and found that the second parameter of http.get expects a RequestOptionsArgs interface, which URLSearchParams does not implement. Wrapping the searchParams inside a RequestOptions object works. Would be nice to have a shortcut though.

Comment: You are totally right, I forgot `RequestOptions`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out deprecation of `search`. Fixed my prob

Comment: Thank you for pointing this change out! All docs and issues I've found for hours have been telling me to attach params to `search` property.

Answer (score 84):

### Version 5+

With Angular 5 and up, you **DON'T have to use HttpParams**. You can directly send your json object as shown below.

```
let data = {limit: "2"};
this.httpClient.get<any>(apiUrl, {params: data});
```

Please note that data values should be string, ie; `{ params: {limit: "2"}}`

### Version 4.3.x+

Use **HttpParams, HttpClient** from **@angular/common/http**

```
import { HttpParams, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
...
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { ... }
...
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append("page", 1);
....
this.httpClient.get<any>(apiUrl, {params: params});
```

Also, try stringifying your nested object using `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score 18):

**Angular 6**

You can pass in parameters needed for get call by using params:

```
this.httpClient.get<any>(url, { params: x });
```

where x = { property: "123" }.

As for the api function that logs "123":

```
router.get('/example', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query.property);
})
```

Comment: That's was a change added in version 5. Already added here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45455904/3276721

Answer (score 9):

My example

```
private options = new RequestOptions({headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})});
```

My method

```
  getUserByName(name: string): Observable<MyObject[]> {
    //set request params
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set("name", name);
    //params.set("surname", surname); for more params
    this.options.search = params;

    let url = "http://localhost:8080/test/user/";
    console.log("url: ", url);

    return this.http.get(url, this.options)
      .map((resp: Response) => resp.json() as MyObject[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return Observable.throw(err || 'Server error');
  }
```

in my  component

```
  userList: User[] = [];
  this.userService.getUserByName(this.userName).subscribe(users => {
      this.userList = users;
    });
```

By postman

```
http://localhost:8080/test/user/?name=Ethem
```

Answer (score 8):

In latest Angular 7/8, you can use the simplest approach:-

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

getDetails(searchParams) {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        params: { ...searchParams}
    };
    return this.http.get(this.Url, httpOptions);
}
```

Comment: This won't work if any of `searchParams`' properties are not `string` values.

Comment: Correct, doesn't work on angular 13: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error TS2769 (TS) No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 15, '(url: string, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ headers: { 'Content-Type': string; }; params: { isReset: boolean; }; }' is not assignable to paramet...

Answer (score 4):

If you plan on sending more than one parameter.

#### Component

```
private options = {
  sort:   '-id',
  select: null,
  limit:  1000,
  skip:   0,
  from:   null,
  to:     null
};

constructor(private service: Service) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getAllItems(this.options)
    .subscribe((item: Item[]) => {
      this.item = item;
    });
}
```

#### Service

```
private options = new RequestOptions({headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})});
constructor(private http: Http) { }

getAllItems(query: any) {
  let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
  for(let key in query){
    params.set(key.toString(), query[key]);
  }
  this.options.search = params;
  this.header = this.headers();
```

And continue with your http request just how @ethemsulan did.

#### Server side route

```
router.get('/api/items', (req, res) => {
  let q = {};
  let skip = req.query.skip;
  let limit = req.query.limit;
  let sort  = req.query.sort;
  q.from = req.query.from;
  q.to = req.query.to;

  Items.find(q)
    .skip(skip)
    .limit(limit)
    .sort(sort)
    .exec((err, items) => {
      if(err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          title: "An error occurred",
          error: err
        });
      }
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Success",
        obj:  items
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: In the get request on your service I am missing how you are handling the get request.

Comment: Oh I guess you would put the http get request in that method as a return like ethumsulan's answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use **HttpParams** from @angular/common/http and pass a string with the query.
For example:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
const query = 'key=value' // date=2020-03-06

const options = {
  params: new HttpParams({
    fromString: query
  })
}
```

Now in your code

```
this.http.get(urlFull, options);
```

And this works for you :)

I hoppe help you

Answer (score 0):

```
import ...
declare var $:any;
...
getSomeEndPoint(params:any): Observable<any[]> {
    var qStr = $.param(params); //<---YOUR GUY
    return this._http.get(this._adUrl+"?"+qStr)
      .map((response: Response) => <any[]> response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

provided that you have [installed jQuery](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation), I do `npm i jquery --save` and include in `apps.scripts` in `angular-cli.json`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
constructor(private _http: Http, private router: Router) {
}

return this._http.get('http://url/login/' + email + '/' + password)
       .map((res: Response) => {
           return res.json();
        }).catch(this._handleError);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Url Parameters](https://angular.io/guide/http#url-parameters) from the official documentation.

Example: `this.httpClient.get(this.API, { params: new HttpParams().set('noCover', noCover) })`