# Angular 2 http.get with params

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I want to send query parameters within a GET request. My class looks like this:

```
 @Injectable()
 export class Loader implements TranslateLoader{
  constructor(private http: Http){
   }
   getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any>
   {
     return this.http.get(routes.Localization.Get) ;// in that place I need to pass params
   }
 }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass url arguments (query string) to a HTTP request on Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475523/how-to-pass-url-arguments-query-string-to-a-http-request-on-angular-2)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can leverage the `URLSearchParams` class for this:

```
getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
  let params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.set('param1', 'value1');

  return this.http.get(routes.Localization.Get, { search: params });
}
```

This will result to an URL like this (parameters are added in the query string): `http://...?param1=value1`.

See the documentation of this class:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html

It now providers support for encoding / decoding parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I try this: https://gyazo.com/d84e2f55d3df86030aa5ed01b0f99a0c  but I have null value in my server controller https://gyazo.com/bf675ca73b88c858afb39982aa105a99

Comment: You're welcome! It seems that you try to get your params from payload and not from query string. Whereas it's not forbidden for GET requests, it's better to leverage the query string...

Comment: Any guess why my .set function would fail? It looks like it's not altering the URLSearchParams object at all.

Answer (score 12):

This is pretty simple - you can define your `URLSearchParams` and pass them in the second parameter of the `http.get` method:

```
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http'

let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('param1', 'someValue');
params.set('param2', 'someValue');

return this.http.get(routes.Localization.Get, { search: params });
```

Comment: Remember to add this line at top:
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

Comment: this bugger had me!

Answer (score -8):

When an URL like this http://stackoverflow.com?param1=value

You can get the param1 by code follow:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: '',
    templateUrl: './abc.html',
    styleUrls: ['./abc.less']
})
export class AbcComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // get param
        let param1 = this.route.snapshot.queryParams["param1"];
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is very old. It also asks how to SET params, not how to read them.

Comment: Sorry,
The title is "Angular 2 http.get with params". I've only focused on the title (only GET without SET). If have any missing pls forget it.

Comment: the question refers to setting parameters for a http.get request