# Angular2 Post request parameter handling in C#

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

**Angular 2 Code**
Request URl: http://loacalhost:8800/MyController/SaveBookings

```
let data = {
    occupationListStr: occupations,
    rOccupationListStr: roccsStr,
};
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this.http.post('MyController/SaveBookings', JSON.stringify(data),options)
    .then(res => {  
        return res.json()
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

**C# code**

Controller

**Issue:** Request.QueryString values occupationListStr and  rOccupationListStr are null

```
public ActionResult SaveBookings()
{
    dynamic occupationListStr = Request.QueryString["occupationListStr"];
    dynamic rOccupationListStr = Request.QueryString["rOccupationListStr"];

    <....Do something.....>

    return <return something>;
}
```

Comment: You are not sending those values as query parameters, you are actually parsing them in a string and sending it on the request body.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41533506/1876572

Comment: If you go down the route of query strings, once you have changed the Angular Code, I'd suggest changing the method signature to `public ActionResult SaveBookingsPost([FromQuery]string occupationListStr, [FromQuery]string rOccupationListStr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you send data as `Json` (using `JSON.stringify(data)`) in request body but in your action you expect data from query string.

You should either parse `Json` in your action to some model:

```
// you can use your own model (some class to parse Json to) instead of "dynamic"
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveBookings([FromBody]dynamic data) 
{
    var occupationListStr = data.occupationListStr;
    var rOccupationListStr = data.rOccupationListStr;

    <....Do something.....>

    return <return something>;
}
```

**OR**

you should change your request in Angular 2:

```
this.http.post('MyController/SaveBookings?occupationListStr=' + occupations + '&rOccupationListStr=' + roccsStr, null, options)
    .then(res => {  
        return res.json()
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

1. You dont need to stringify
2. Create a class in backend (say `Occupation`) with occupationListStr, rOccupationListStr properties
3. From the class you can automatically create controller with scaffolding. If you dont want

`[httpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Occupation objOccupation)
{
}`