# Http get params filter

Tags: angular, http, parameters, get

I try use in Angular http.get with params :

i put to get (data)

```
getAllVM(data) {
        console.log('data', data, 'params' ,(getParamString(data)));
        return this.http.get(environment.apiEndpoint + '/vendorMachine', {params: {filters: data}});
}
```

results consol.log =>

```
data {status: Array(0), groups: Array(1)}groups: [2]status: []__proto__: Object params ?status=&groups=2
```

in header i send:

```
?filters=%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

how can i change this to correct?

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280303/angular-http-get-with-parameter/44282037

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass url arguments (query string) to a HTTP request on Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475523/how-to-pass-url-arguments-query-string-to-a-http-request-on-angular)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Add get parameters as below to your http get request.**

```
getAllVM(data) {

    const params = new HttpParams().set('filters', JSON.stringify(data));
    return this.http.get(environment.apiEndpoint + '/vendorMachine', { params: params });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular does not offer filters as option.

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient

use this instead:

this.http.get(`$(environment.apiEndpoint)/vendorMachine?filters=${data}`)

if data is a json use JSON.stringfy(data)