# Service return array of objects instead of object

Tags: angular, typescript

I got simple service

```
  getHotels(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(API_URL + '/hotels');
  }
```

and in my component I got

```
  getHotels() {
    this.workersService.getHotels().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.hotels = res;
        console.log(this.hotels);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

and output from `console.log` is

```
[{…}]
0: {id: 1, id_hotel: "123", client: "test", date: "17.08.2020", team: 1, …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

And I got acces by for example `this.hotels[0].client` but I want `this.hotels.client`
How Can I get just object instead of array of objects?

Comment: I think the issue is in the other way, why are you using it like a single object when the service is returning you an array of objects?

Comment: How would you know which hotel you want?

Comment: cause it will always be single object

Comment: @PoulKruijt base on number of reservation. I got the same field in my hotels table and users so I am getting only this hotel where reservation number are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is called `getHotels()`, your URL ends with `/hotels`, this all implies the server returns an array. You should either change your server, or map the response to the first item:

```
this.workersService.getHotels().pipe(
  map((hotels) => hotels[0])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The specific endpoint you are calling `this.http.get(API_URL + '/hotels')` is returning an array of objects so unfortunately you will always receive an array, even if there is only one object in it. There is nothing technically wrong with this, `this.hotels[0].client` is a perfectly normal/acceptable way to handle an endpoint which returns a list of one item.

That said if you must have a single object returned, the endpoint itself needs to be informed to return one object in some way.

If you are calling a public API, check the documentation to see whether:

- there is a more specific endpoint to be calling (e.g. `this.http.get(API_URL + '/hotels/' + hotelId`), where `hotelId` contains the ID of a specific hotel
- whether the endpoint supports custom headers (e.g. `this.http.get(API_URL + '/hotels', headers`), where `headers` is a headers object (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280303/angular-http-get-with-parameter/44282037) for more)

If you instead own the API, you would need to implement one of the methods above first and then use it in the same way.