# Diffrent solution to send query params to controller using Angular

Tags: angular, http, request, query-string

I have a `Spring` controller which takes one argument - `Pageable`:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Page<Item> getAll(Pageable pageable) {    
        return itemService.findAll(pageable);
    }
```

Via `Postman` I can call this `api` by providing `query params` as: `http://localhost:8080/api/item/all?page=0&size=2` and I got a `json` response with two elements.

How can I call this kind of api in `Angular 4`? Is there any other way to send `query params` in `Angular 4` than this?:

```
getItems(page, size){
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/all?page=' + page + '&size=' + size);
  }
```

I would like to use something like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let search = new URLSearchParams();
    search.set('page', '0');
    search.set('size', "2");
    console.log('------------', search);
    this.itemService.getItems({search:search})
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log('teitems', res.json());
        this.items = res.json().content;
      });
  }
```

But generally it doesn't work at all and the search object looks suspicious because of the fact:
[image]

What is more in `network` tab of my browser request looks like:

[image]

So as you see the `request URL` differ from that which I posted above from `Postman`.

Comment: getItems() expects two arguments, page and size, which are supposed to be numbers. You call it with a single argument, which is an object (`getItems({search:search})`). How could that work?

Comment: I also checked it and doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a lot like the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475523/how-to-pass-url-arguments-query-string-to-a-http-request-on-angular-2).
Look at the answers there.

In summary:

```
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

params = params.append('var1', val1);

this.http.get('base_url', {params: params});
```

You could also manually build your param object (not use HttpParams).

```
this.http.get('base_url', {params: {'var1': val1}});
```

Comment: In this solution my `request url` still looks like `http://localhost:4200/api/item/all` without those parameters so the `rest controller` can't read it properly.