# Angular4 http get with URL parameter

Tags: angular, rest, typescript

I want to invoke a REST API in Angular4 containing URL parameters. The template looks like that:

```
http://localhost:61448/api/Product/language/{languauge}/name/{name}
```

This is a working example:

```
http://localhost:61448/api/Product/language/en-us/name/apple
```

I know I can just concat the URL myself:

```
this.http.get<Array<ProductResponse>>('http://localhost:61448/api/Product/language/' + 'en-us' + '/name/' + 'apple',)
      .subscribe(data => {
      // do something with data
    });
```

But I was hoping to find a better solution using something like `HttpParams`:

```
const params = new HttpParams()
.set('language', 'en-us')
.set('name', 'apple');

this.http.get<Array<ProductResponse>>('http://localhost:61448/api/Product', {params : params}).subscribe(data => {
  // do something with data
});
```

But this will generate the following request (containing query parameter):

```
http://localhost:61448/api/Product?language=en-us&name=apple
```

Is there any way to generate the right URL without concat it myself?

Comment: Take a look at this answer... [https://stackoverflow.com/a/41533506/5874913](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41533506/5874913)

Comment: @seven Your suggested answers doesn't help me, they are using query parameters! Please remove the duplicate flag.

Comment: The answer is no. Just use template strings to make it slightly more readable.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, template string will make it more readable, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of:

```
this.http.get<Array<ProductResponse>>('http://localhost:61448/api/Product/language/' + 'en-us' + '/name/' + 'apple',)
      .subscribe(data => {
      // do something with data
    });
```

do:

```
this.http.get<Array<ProductResponse>>(`http://localhost:61448/api/Product/language/${languauge}/name/${name}`,)
      .subscribe(data => {
      // do something with data
    });
```

where `language` and `name` are your params.

notice special quotes character for url and your params must be inside `${}`

ref link:
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/template-strings.html

Comment: Thats not exactly what I was looking for but way better then my aproach and enough for me. Thanks!

Comment: well, from my understanding of your question, what you're looking for is pretty much impossible as typescript/angular cannot know where in the url to puth which variable. you have to have anchors for it. and that's what this methods is for.