# Trying to do a http.post request with a string as the payload

Tags: angular, rest, http, post

Im trying to send an http.post request from my angular app to the rest server using the following code:

I'm using: `import { Http } from '@angular/http';`

```
let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
let data: string = 'wing,wheel';
this.http.post('http://172.16.2.209:3000/api/AddPartList?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx',{headers: headers},data)
```

But I keep getting the error `Response with status: 422 Unprocessable Entity for URL`

The curl command for what I want to do is:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "$class": "org.blockaviation.AddPartList", \ 
   "partListId": "1", \ 
   "partList": "wing,wheel", \ 
   "plane": "resource:org.blockaviation.Plane#Plane_001" \ 
   \ 
 }' 'http://172.16.2.209:3000/api/AddPartList'
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how to do this properly?

Comment: Your `post` parameters are in the wrong order. It goes URL, data, then options (like headers).

Comment: I have seen that but if I do: `this.http.post('http://172.16.2.209:3000/api/AddPartList?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx',data,{headers: headers})` I get the following error:Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'Headers'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.

Comment: You can find an answer for that issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475523/how-to-pass-url-arguments-query-string-to-a-http-request-on-angular).

Comment: Got it working thank you all so much for your answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your headers inside a RequestOptions object like this:

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

private requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
    headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
});

this.http.post(this.url, data, this.requestOptions);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using something like `json-server`

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(data), options)...
```

Comment: Did the trick, BUT you might want to spell stringify correctly... ;^)