# How to post data using REST API in suite crm

Tags: php, rest, api, suitecrm

This is my `rest.php` file

```
<?php
chdir('../../..');

require_once 'SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom.php';

$webservice_path = 'service/core/SugarRestService.php';
$webservice_class = 'SugarRestService';
$webservice_impl_class = 'SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom';
$registry_path = 'custom/service/v4_1_custom/registry.php';
$registry_class = 'registry_v4_1_custom';
$location = 'custom/service/v4_1_custom/rest.php';

require_once 'service/core/webservice.php';
```

This is my SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom.php file where i have written custom methods

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

if(!defined('sugarEntry')){
  define('sugarEntry', true);
}
require_once 'service/v4_1/SugarWebServiceImplv4_1.php';

class SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom extends SugarWebServiceImplv4_1
{ 
    public function custom_test($username)
    {
         $arr = array ('a'=>$username,'b'=>22,'c'=>32,'d'=>44,'e'=>55);

         return json_encode($arr);
        die;
    }
}
```

This is my registry.php file where i have registered my custom method

```
<?php
    require_once 'service/v4_1/registry.php';
    class registry_v4_1_custom extends registry_v4_1
    {
        protected function registerFunction()
        {
            parent::registerFunction();

              $this->serviceClass->registerFunction('custom_test',
                                                  array(
                                                    'username'=>'xsd:string),
                                                  array(
                                                    'return'=>'tns:get_array')
                                                  );


        }
    }
```

The problem is when i am passing the the data through get method Like this

> http://www.example.com/custom/service/v4_1_custom/rest.php?method=custom_test&input_type=json&response_type=json&rest_data=
>
> > {"username":"some
> >      username"}

i am getting the result but i dont know how to pass it through post method through IOS application. I tried to pass it but I am not getting anything in username. 
I checked the response through curl as well , it is working using curl, But i have to connect it to IOS. 
Help will be appreciated

Actually we are building a Hybrid app for IOS using Angular 5 and Ionic 3
Here is the code 
auth-services.ts

```
public login(credentials){

        if(credentials.username === null || credentials.password === null){

            return Observable.throw("Please enter credentials");
        } else {

            this.username1 = credentials.username;
            this.password1 = credentials.password;

            return Observable.create(observer =>{
             // At this point make a request to your backend to make a real check!

            this.method1 = "custom_test";
            this.inputType = "JSON";
            this.responseType = "JSON";
            this.encryptionValue = "PLAIN";


            this.bodyData = {};    //get method calling
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.bodyData));

             //Sending the Username and Password to the Web Server for authentication. Change the URL Get the response message
            this.servicesProvider.restApi("post","http://exmaple.com/custom/service/v4_1_custom/rest.php",this.bodyData).then(
                (res) => {
                    console.log("Response stringify :",JSON.stringify(res));
                    console.log("Response parse :", res);

                    console.log("Status :",res.status);
                    this.response = res.status;  //TODO: Replace res.username with res.message as we have to check for user exist or not.
                    if(this.response == "success out") {
                        this.success = true;

                        this.storage.set("status",this.response); //Username value stored in localstorage

                        this.currentUser = new User('Simon', 'saimon@devdactic.com');
                        observer.next(this.success);
                        observer.complete();
                    } else {
                        this.success = false;
                        observer.next(this.success);
                        observer.complete();
                    }
                } 
            ); 

    }
```

Here is the services.ts file. this is a common rest api file for sending rest api requests.

```
restApi(method,url,data) {

      console.log("inside restApi");


    switch(method) {
      case 'post' : { 
                    console.log("Inside Post Method");
                    /*
                    return this.httpClient.post(url,data)
                    .subscribe(
                      (res:any) => {
                        console.log("POST response below");
                        console.log(res.username);
                        this.responseData = JSON.stringify(res);
                        console.log("ResponseData Value");
                        console.log(this.responseData);

                        return this.responseData;
                      }); */

                     let headers = new Headers({'content-type':'application/json'});
                     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers:this.headers });
                     this.responseFromFunction = this.http.post(url,data).toPromise()
                     .then(this.extractData)
                     .catch(this.handleError);

                     break; 

      }

      case 'get' : {
                    console.log("Inside Get Method");
                    let headers = new Headers({'content-type':'application/json'});
                    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers:this.headers });
                    this.responseFromFunction = this.http.get(url, options).toPromise()
                    .then(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
                    break;
      }

      case 'put' : {
                    console.log("Inside Put Method");
                    this.responseFromFunction = this.httpClient.put(url,data)
                    .subscribe((res:any) => {
                      console.log(res);
                    });
                    break;
      }

      case 'delete' : {
                        console.log("Inside Delete Method");
                        this.responseFromFunction = this.httpClient.delete(url)
                        .subscribe((res:any) => {
                          console.log(res);
                        });
                        break;

      }

      default : {
                    this.responseFromFunction = {"message":"error"};
                console.log("Unknow Method Entered. Or write method in small lowercase only"); 
                // return "Invalid Method";
                }
    }
    console.log("Outside switch case");
    console.log(this.responseFromFunction);
    return this.responseFromFunction;
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
  //  console.log("Resp :", res.json());
  //  console.log("Stringy :", JSON.stringify(res));
    return res.json();

  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }

}
```

here is the postman response
[image]

I am not getting how to pass username in rest_data

Comment: Where is your iOS code?

Comment: I just edited my code please check.

Comment: Yes it is working with get method but not with post. We checked it using POSTMAN but its not working there using post as well

Comment: check the postman screenshot please

Comment: I am getting the response but as I have passed the value of username through post but i didn't get it in response.

Comment: ok that means your postman request working fine .. now you need to deal with that dynamic `$username`

Comment: but first you need to check the updated answer below and update us whether its working or not mam.

Comment: Let me know if the answer helps you to solve a problem or we can check other ways.

Comment: your issue solved mam ? or still any issue ?

Comment: I will update.... sever is not responding now so not able to check.. thats why dint update here

Comment: no worries mam .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

IF you are using Angular 5 then :

[Documentation read it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475523/how-to-pass-url-arguments-query-string-to-a-http-request-on-angular)

**Making a POST request**

Apps often POST data to a server. They POST when submitting a form. In the following example, the HeroesService posts when adding a hero to the database.
app/heroes/heroes.service.ts (addHero)

```
/** POST: add a new hero to the database */
addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
    );
}
```

The `HttpClient.post()` method is similar to get() in that it has a type parameter (you're expecting the server to return the new hero) and it takes a resource URL.

**It takes two more parameters:**

```
hero - the data to POST in the body of the request.
`httpOptions` - the method options which, in this case, specify required headers.
```

Of course it catches errors in much the same manner described above.

The `HeroesComponent` initiates the actual POST operation by subscribing to the Observable returned by this service method.
app/heroes/heroes.component.ts (addHero)

```
this.heroesService.addHero(newHero)
  .subscribe(hero => this.heroes.push(hero));
```

When the server responds successfully with the newly added hero, the component adds that hero to the displayed heroes list.

**Edited Answer:**

I saw your postman screenshot you are passing username

[This link will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475523/how-to-pass-url-arguments-query-string-to-a-http-request-on-angular)

Comment: It's working when I am sending the POST request to http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts url and getting the same data as response which I am sending in POST request. So my Angular code is working properly.