# How to include parameter in HTTP request with Angular 6

Tags: angular, http, angular-services, angular-httpclient

I need to call the following endpoint `https://sample_url?id=12345` from an Angular service.

UserService

```
getUsersByGroupID(id): Observable<User[]> {
 var url = 'https://sample_url';

 var params = new HttpParams();
 params = params.append('id', id);

 this.data = this.http.get<User[]>(url, {params: params}, this.httpConfig.getHeaderOptions()).pipe(catchError(this.handleError('getData', [])));
 return this.data;
}
```

In one of my components I should do something like...

```
  this.userService.getUsersByGroupID(sys_id).toPromise().then(users => {
   this.users = users as User[]
}
```

but i'm not sure how to include the query parameter `?id=`correctly. I tried looking at [How to pass url arguments (query string) to a HTTP request on Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475523/how-to-pass-url-arguments-query-string-to-a-http-request-on-angular) but didn't help much.

Thanks.

Comment: btw, `this.httpConfig.getHeaderOptions()` is the header for the request, which is correct since I'm using it in another http request that does not require any parameter in the url

Comment: Why oh why don't you simply read the documentation? https://angular.io/guide/http#url-parameters, https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get. get() expects **2** arguments, not 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getUsersByGroupID(id: number): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>("https://sample_url?id=" + id)
        .pipe(
             map(response => {
                 return response;
    }));
}
```

Comment: You may add some description to your answer to explain what changes have you made.

Comment: Can you describe this solution ? and if it's really working, can you please give us the Output ? Thank you! It can help a lot of junior developers :)