# angular5 and http GET query parameters - looks like dedicated object (HttpParams or UrlSearchParams) do not work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have a strange problem I cannot understand. Here is the code calling REST endpoint:

```
this.http.get<AllApplicationType[]>(environment.SUDS_API_SERVICE_URL + environment.SUDS_ALL_APPLICATIONS_URL, this.setQueryParams(page, size)).toPromise() ...
```

where setQueryParams function look like this:

```
setQueryParams(page?: number, size?: number): {} {
const startFrom = page * size + 1;
const params = new HttpParams();
params.set('startFrom', startFrom.toString());
params.set('maxRecords', size.toString());
return params;
```

}

When the request comes to my backend query params are null, somehow they are not being passed over but why ? Is this not the right method or what ?

Comment: are you using HttpClient? it looks like you are but can you please clarify? also, url parameters dont go in the headers, they go in the url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass url arguments (query string) to a HTTP request on Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475523/how-to-pass-url-arguments-query-string-to-a-http-request-on-angular)

Comment: The URL in my code is static and has no params. My intention is to call this URL with Query Parameters like this:                   http://localhost:7001/suds/pending-registration-finder/findAll?startFrom=5&maxRecords=10

Answer (score -1):

It just occurred that using HttpParams or URLSearchParams objects do not work at all. All tries with these 2 failed in my case.
The only way is to build parameters explicitly like this:

```
setRequestParams(page?: number, size?: number): {} {
const startFrom = page * size + 1;
const params = {'startFrom': startFrom.toString(), 'maxRecords': size.toString()};
const options = {params: params};
return options;
```

}

Well I beleive this is a bug in Angular HttpClient.