# Angular: pass Parameter to this.http.get()

Tags: angular

I have an angular APP that need dynamically get the data from API. when I use static URL its work properly.

here my code

`service.ts`

```
export interface MachineData {
  name: string;
  status: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class MachineService {
  BASE_URL = 'example.com/api/v1/id/1';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMachineData() {
    return this.http.get(this.BASE_URL);
  }
}
```

`component.ts`

```
showMachine() {
    this.machineService.getMachineData()
    .subscribe((data: machineData) => this.machineData = {
        status: data['status'],
    });
}

markers: marker[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Marker A",
        lat: -6.949065,
        lng: 107.592339,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Marker B",
        lat: -6.935582,
        lng: 107.610037,
    }
]
```

`component.html`

```
<agm-marker
    *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
    (markerClick)="showMachine(m.id, i)"
    [latitude]="m.lat"
    [longitude]="m.lng"
    [label]="m.name">

    <agm-info-window>
        <strong>
            <p>Status : {{machineData.status}}</p>
        </strong>
    </agm-info-window>
</agm-marker>
```

how to make the URL dynamic?... I mean add the ID to the URL.

example:

from this

```
return this.http.get(this.BASE_URL);
```

to this

```
return this.http.get(this.BASE_URL + id);
```

so I can retrieve data by id. already trying by do like this :

on my `component.html`

```
(markerClick)="showMachine(m.id)"
```

on my `component.ts`

```
showMachine(id: number) {
    this.machineService.getMachineData(id: number)
    .subscribe((data: machineData) => this.machineData = {
        status: data['status'],
    });
}
```

and my `service.ts`

```
return this.http.get(this.BASE_URL + id);
```

but it's not work.

Comment: are you getting any error

Comment: console log the dynamic URL code and check it matches with static one.

Comment: I guess you should check the dynamic URl value first... this.BASE_URL + id is correct?

Comment: This seems pretty simple if you use debugger, you should debug it and resolve.

Comment: @Justcode any link guide?...

Comment: @JihoonKwon the url is correct, when i use `example.com/api/v1/id/1` its show the data, id `1 and 2` have the data. but when use `this.BASE_URL + id` its show nothing, did my `id` pass correctly?...

Comment: @DickyRaambo use chrome debugger to inspect your code.

Comment: @DickyRaambo I meant please check the this.BASE_URL + id first. 
ex : 
const finalUrl = this.BASE_URL + id; 
console.log("final url : ", finalUrl);
If this url is correct, then you can check the response which client received from server. or You should check server logs ( request / response ) :)

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475523/how-to-pass-url-arguments-query-string-to-a-http-request-on-angular

Comment: Try this...

 BASE_URL = 'example.com/api/v1';
getMachineData(id) {
let Params = new HttpParams();
       Params = Params.append('id', id);
    return this.http.get(this.BASE_URL,{ params: Params });
  }

Answer (score 0):

id is a number, URL a string.

Thus, you want to convert the id to string first before doing "url + id".

i.e. something like this does work. Without the "toString" you will get "NaN" in the concatenation.

```
let url: string;
let id: number;

id = 5
url = "http://something/";

let result = url + id.toString();

console.log(result);
```