# getting null in get serviece call without error in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, web-services

i get null in the subscribe statemaent,
the Api returns the correct data,
but in angular its accepted as null.
what should be the problem?
here is my subscribe in ts:

```
this.service.getFlightId( this.addFlightForm.controls["date"].value, this.addFlightForm.controls["time"].value,
this.originId,
this.destinationId,
this.addFlightForm.controls["flightNum"].value)
   .subscribe(data=>{
  this.flight=data;
}, err=>{
  this.noFlightId=true;
});
```

and this is my serviece:

```
getFlightId(date:Date,time:Time,originId:number,destinationId:number,flightNum:number):Observable<Flight>{
        return this._http.get<Flight>("/api/flight/"+date+"/"+time+"/"+originId+"/"+destinationId+"/"+flightNum);
    }
```

Comment: Where are you accessing the variable `this.flight` in the component? Please show more code.

Answer (score 0):

As your configurationUrl = "/api/flight/"+date+"/"+time+"/"+originId+"/"+destinationId+"/"+flightNum`. I hope you cannot have any api call with exact parmas like

```
/flight/23-06-2020/12:00/originId/DestinationId/filghtnumber
```

can you check in your backend if you have an API request like this `/api/flight/23-06-2020/12:00/Austria/germany/F121.`

Generally we make http call like below,

```
this.httpClient.get<any>(url, { params: x });
```

Or may be this [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-request-with-query-params) or [stakeoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475523/how-to-pass-url-arguments-query-string-to-a-http-request-on-angular) can help you.