# How to get data from API in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, http, frontend

I have an API with data it takes ID to return a specific data or it return null.
And I want to know how to do it with angular.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass url arguments (query string) to a HTTP request on Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475523/how-to-pass-url-arguments-query-string-to-a-http-request-on-angular)

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: In that case share your code

Comment: `this.http.get
      ('https://www.worldofss.net:8883/api/v1/RequestManagement/Details',
        {
          params:{id:id}
        }
      )`

Comment: And what does not work now?

Comment: It return two errors 
-GET https://www.worldofss.net:8883/api/v1/RequestManagement/Details?Id=8 400
-core.mjs:6469 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: 'OK', url: 'https://www.worldofss.net:8883/api/v1/RequestManagement/Details?Id=8', ok: false, …}

Comment: I don't know this API but after clicking on that link it said `errors":{"Id":["The value '8' is not valid."]}`