# Send Request as JSON param inside JSON object

Tags: android, json, request

I want to send my request parameters in JSON format. My problem is I am not able send request like below format. Can anybody help me to resolve it?

```
{
    "user": {
        "email" : "",
        "password": "",
        "password_confirmation": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Create the JsonObject and set the values which you want

Comment: can you tried this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26542491/8164071)

Comment: You only include example of JSON db. Please include your code that you used for sending the request as you mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
      try {
            JSONObject parent = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            jsonObject.put("email", "email");
            jsonObject.put("password", "password");
            jsonObject.put("password_confirmation", "password_confirmation");
            parent.put("user", jsonObject);
            Log.d("output", parent.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It will return this `JsonObject` output

```
{
    "user": {
        "email" : "email",
        "password": "password",
        "password_confirmation": "password_confirmation"
    }
}
```

Comment: Its very useful. Thank you very much.

Comment: If it works for you, please accept the answer @user3606971

Comment: Can you help me send JSON request as below :

{ "gigs_list_ids" : {
            "2640" : 38
    },
    "gigs_add_ons_list_ids" : {
        "2641" : 65,
        "2642" : 66
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

you are probably looking for something like this

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("email", "value");
            jsonObject.put("password", "value");
            jsonObject.put("password_confirmation", "value");

            JSONObject parent = new JSONObject();
            parent.put("user", jsonObject);
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```